# Windows Phone SDK & Visual Studio Setup

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using **Visual Studio 2012** and Want to do Windows Phone Development on This Visual Studio so can anyone Suggest me Which WPF SDK Should I download , I download **Windows Phone SDK 7.1** , but it is giving me an error and I can't install WPF 8 as it needs 64 bit OS and I don't have it, please suggest me some suitable configuration to work on 32 bit OS and 32 bit machine with Visual Studio 2012.

I don't want to install Windows Phone 8 SDK on my 32 bit machine I just want to know whether there is any solution exist by which I can develop apps in Windows Phone with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: this is not duplicate @Bart see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solutions to develop for Windows Phone:

- Get the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 and install the Express edition of Visual Studio ([as the SDK is not compatible with VS 2012](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9a926034-5ca8-42fe-927b-a87b285d31b3/visual-studio-windows-phone-sdk-71?forum=wptools)).
- Get a machine with 64bit and [SLAT](http://www.howtogeek.com/73318/how-to-check-if-your-cpu-supports-second-level-address-translation-slat/) support to install Windows Phone SDK 8.0.
- Get the same new machine, but use [VS 2015 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) (free) to create apps for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 10.
- Use [Windows App Studio](http://appstudio.windows.com/en-us) (really, don't).
- Get Xamarin, PhoneGap (or another cross-platform tool) and hope it works on your current machine, if not, get that new machine after all.

Conclusion: Get a 64bit machine :)

---

Note that while 7.1 apps will *most likely* run on later versions, they might not scale correctly to the new resolutions, have a few quirks and certainly you'll miss out on a **lot** of new features. If you start on a new app I'd recommend you to go for either 8.1 or even Windows 10 (depending if you want to support desktop-tablets and maybe even Xbox, HoloLens, ...).

Compare it to Android: if you start on a new app today, you won't create a 1.5 (Cupcake) / 1.6 (Donut) / 2.0 (Eclair) app. I guess you'd go for at least 4.1 (Jelly Bean) for new features and drop the 5% of users that use older versions.